# Null JSON response

Tags: ios, json, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

```
NSString *connection = @"http:"(link);

dispatch_queue_t queue  =  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:connection];
    NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSLog(@"\nJSON: %@ \n Error: %@", json, error);

    if(!error) {
        NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
        NSMutableArray *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", jsonDict);        
    }
});
```

The above code returns :

```
JSON: "{\"value\":[{\"Id\":\" }}
```

but 
   `NSData` is `69746963 735c222c 5c224973 41767469 76655c22 3a5c2231 5c222c`
and `jsonDict` returns `(null)`.

I am confused what may be going on.
Can somebody please help me figure it out.

I am trying to get the JSON data but it returns null.

Thanks

Comment: The log of the NSData is fine. That's the bytes, not pointers. Log the error from the call to JSONObjectWithData.

Comment: Looks like the json being returned isn't valid, so NSJSONSerialization is failing. is error nil for that?

Comment: Erro : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7f8cbacbc2e0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}    How Can I fix this error? Is it only possible through the web service itself? -> JamesSugrue

Comment: Everything is fine, you're jus printing bytes.

Comment: Get the server fixed so it returns valid JSON.

Comment: Problem I have data is printing bytes and I want it to convert to JSON. In my case JSON data after serialization is null. As JamesSugrue pointed out, it returns the error 3840. How can I go around working it?

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, JamesSugrue and Pablo A.

Comment: Shouldnt the `jsonDict` be an actual `NSDictionary` or is it an array?

Comment: I don't think it matters what actually the data type is. I was trying NSLog to print out the stuffs and see for myself what actually it returns. As everybody pointed out it seems the problem is server doesn't give valid json data.

Answer (score 1):

You say the server gave you this:

```
JSON: "{\"value\":[{\"Id\":\" }}
```

If I remove the backslashes that were added by the NSLog command, the actual JSON that you received was

```
{"value":[{"Id":" }}
```

That isn't valid JSON. That's all there is to it; the server sent you rubbish data, and there is no way to get any information from it. Contact the people creating the server software and ask them to fix the problem.

And you really, really need to distinguish between what an object really contains, and what NSLog prints. NSLog prints the contents of an NSData object by displaying each byte as two hexadecimal digits.

Comment: For some reasons, when I copy the data itself from the web service and run it in JSONLint (jsonValidator), it says the data is JSON valid. but When I copy paste the website link , it says the data is not JSON valid. I was wondering what may be the problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these (array or dictionary) without converting it into JSON, depending on what u want :

```
NSString *connection = @"http://(link)";

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:connection]];
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:connection]];
    NSLog(@"DICT: %@ ARRAY: %@", jsonDict, jsonArray);
});
```

I haven't tried it, please paste results?

Comment: Emotality it still returns null                                                                        DICT: (null) ARRAY: (null)

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your `NSString` response, it starts with `{` and ends with `}` which means it is a `NSDictionary`.

Change :

```
NSMutableArray *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

to :

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: For some reasons, it starts with "" and ends with "" marks. So, I think that may be the reason we are not getting any type of data from the web service.                                                                                                      JSON: "{\"value\":[{\"Id\":\" }}

Comment: Is your content type set to plain text or what? `header("Content-Type:text/plain");`

Comment: Try changing between `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` at the top of your PHP using the above code.

Comment: I tried that using www.hurl.it. I still returns the same values. I think the problem is " before the value dictionary starts. I guess I have to talk to the web server handler or have to figure out some way to get rid of " when I get the JSON data

Comment: Yeah its quoting and adding slashes..? Try asking on SuperUser